# NG2: How can I access parent component generically?

Tags: angular

Before I begin please note that I originally asked this question as a feature request at the angular2 github site. However the request was closed and I was advised to post it here. 
Here I am just repeating my initial request. However you can find some discussion by following the link:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10448

I need the ability to obtain a reference to the parent component generically without the child having to know the type of the parent component. Basically I need something like this (pseudocode):

```js
    @Component({
        template: '<child></child>'
        directives: [Child]
    })
    class ParentComponent{}

    @Component({ selector: 'child' })
    class ChildComponent{
        constructor(@Parent() _parent: any){}
    }
```

Basically I need the `_parent` field of the `ChildComponent` to reference the `ParentComponent`. But notice how the type of `_parent` is `any`. It's `any` because it can be any, literally. `ChildComponent` is a generic component that can be used by any type of other component. I know there are solutions out there for this problem but they all entail the child knowing the type of the parent. It goes something like this:

```js
    @Component({ selector: 'child' })
    class ChildComponent{
        constructor(_parent: ParentComponent){}
    }
```

But again, this will not work for me because `ChildComponent` can be used in any type of other component, and neither one knows the type of the other. So what I need is some generic way to inject into `ChildComponent` its parent component, as set in the component tree, without `ChildComponent` knowing the parent type. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: I have few questions as follow : 1) Assume if it is possible, what do you want to do with that? 2) which version of angular2 are you using while asking this question?

Comment: @micronyks thanks... In a nutshell I need to create dynamic components/templates and set their data binding context to the parent component... for more details please see the original issue request... https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10448... thanks

Answer (score 19):

You can use [Injector API](https://angular.io/api/core/INJECTOR) for the same.

**For Angular2 latest release and older versions:**

```js
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";

@Component({ selector: 'child' })
class ChildComponent{
     constructor(private inj:Injector){
         let parentComponent = this.inj.get(AppComponent);
         console.log(parentComponent);
     }
}
```

Comment: thank you @micronyks... but your solution required that ChildComponent know the type of AppComponent... As I mentioned, in my case ChildComponent will not know the type... thanks anyways though...

Comment: Thanks @micronyks. The only problem if parent component doesn't exist it will break the application.

Answer (score 8):

Using `@Input` and a little trick to send the `this` of the parent to the child. I guess you can do it the other way around also, to access child from parent via an `@Output`

#### Parent Component

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: '<app-child [parnt]="var2"></app-child>',
    style: ''
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app works!';
    var1 = "val1";
    var2 = this;
}
```

#### Child Component

```js
import { Component, Input, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: '{{parnt.var1}}',
  style: ''
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() parnt;
}
```

You should see "val1" printed, the value of the var1 of the parent printed in the child template.

Comment: thank you for your response... it works but the problem is that it requires the parent and its template to be modified... thank you though...

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @yurzui for leading me in the right direction... In the end I found a couple of different ways... unfortunately all involve accessing private members which is less than ideal... If anyone knows of a better way, please speak up... thank you

```
 constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef){
    var parentComponent1 = this.vcRef.injector._view.context;
    console.log(parentComponent1);
    var parentComponent2 = this.vcRef._element.parentView.context;
    console.log(parentComponent2);
    console.log(parentComponent1 === parentComponent2);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to make it work.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child'
})
class ChildComponent{
    constructor( @Optional() public myParent: ParentComponent ){}
}
```

You can find more info in [Angular DI docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-navtree)

Comment: Thats not "generic": you writed `ParentComponent` as type for DI - but your link have some other great answers for this question.